# Trick the randomizer in C

Tags: c, random

I want to get random numbers between 1 to 10.
It actually works, but when it's in a loop, I don't really get random numbers.

```
int randomNum;
srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );
randomNum = rand() % 10;
```

I've been spending hours here and in google looking for a solution, but it looks like no one really solved it (or maybe I didn't search good enough).
The value we get from the randomizer depends on the seconds (not miliseconds or something else, like in other programming language) and that's why the numbers are not random.

In addition, I don't want to download a package for C because I run my code in the university labs, and they won't allow it.

Is there anyone with a creative solution for this problem? maybe some mathematic functions?

Comment: Just call `srand` *once* at the beginning of your program.

Comment: You do know you do not have to pass time to srand. You can pass anything you want - http://www.c-faq.com/lib/srand.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To illustrate Sidoh's answer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;

    srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", 1 + (rand() % 10));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

This produced the following results for my one time seed using time( ).

```
7 10 2 4 4 4 2 1 7 7 10 4 3 10 2 9 6 9 2 9 7 10 4 1 1 8 2 4 8 1 2
4 2 3 9 5 8 1 7 4 9 8 10 1 8 1 1 5 1 4 5 7 3 9 10 3 6 1 9 3 4 10
8 5 2 7 2 2 9 10 5 9 8 4 1 7 7 2 3 7 5 8 6 10 8 5 4 3 7 2 8 2 1 7
7 5 5 10 6 5
```

Comment: The problem was that <<<srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );>>> was in the loop. Thanks a lot, it works now.

Comment: Just modding that way is really horrible from a distribution standpoint.

Comment: @Randy can you elaborate? It would be interesting to hear why.

Comment: @DaveNewman Too long to write it all out in a comment, but this link covers the issues in detail.  http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html

Comment: @Randy Thanks! I personally have not written production code that needed any random number generators, and I was vaguely aware that rand( ) was problematic, but didn't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Do not seed the random number generator more than once. Since your code probably runs all within the same second, every query to `rand` uses the same seed, so you'll get the same number every time.

Answer (score 1):

Dave Newman provides a very good answer.
Alternatively, you could also try a pseudo random generator, for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a0; // this value will be our requirement
    int mod = 11; //this is the limit (0 - mod-1), here 10
    int a; // this stores the previous value of a0;
    int i; // loop variable
    int mul=25; //multiplicative factor
    int add=3; // additive factor
    int limit=100; // our limit
    srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) ); // initialize the seed
    a0 = rand() % mod;
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a0);
        a = a0;
        a0 = (a * mul + add) % mod;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

The output::

---

1st run::

```
2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6
7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8
0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3
1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10
4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9
2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9
```

---

2nd output::

```
9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0
6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1
8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4
3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2
10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7       9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7
9       2       10      4       3       1       8       0       6       7
```

---